# How to add new field for save and retrieve image from sql database

Tags: android

I read [this tutorial](http://androidhub4you.blogspot.com/2012/09/hello-friends-today-i-am-going-to-share.html) and edit this and add new field Image of type Blob but i m confuse how to do this i try but not solving please help me how i do this? how to add image in database what is wrong in my code how i browse and upload image and save in database and then retrieve? please edit my code how i add new field image in my code?

```
       public class AddEditCountry extends Activity {

 private long rowID; 
 private EditText nameEt;
 private EditText capEt;
 private EditText codeEt;

 private EditText Donedate;
 private EditText Notes;
 private EditText Person;
 private  ImageView imageView1;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
      setContentView(R.layout.add_country);

      nameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Address);
      capEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Stage);
      codeEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Dueby);

      Donedate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Donedate);

      Notes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Notes);
      Person = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Person);

      imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
      Button Browse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Browse);






      Browse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {               
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });        






      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

      if (extras != null)
      {
         rowID = extras.getLong("row_id");
         nameEt.setText(extras.getString("name"));  
         capEt.setText(extras.getString("cap"));  
         codeEt.setText(extras.getString("code"));  
         Donedate.setText(extras.getString("Location"));  
         Notes.setText(extras.getString("Notes")); 
         Person.setText(extras.getString("Person")); 
         imageView1.setTag(extras.getString("Image"));
      }

      Button saveButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
      saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v) 
          {
             if (nameEt.getText().length() != 0)
             {
                AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> saveContactTask = 
                   new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() 
                   {
                      @Override
                      protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
                      {
                         saveContact();
                         return null;
                      }

                      @Override
                      protected void onPostExecute(Object result) 
                      {
                         finish();
                      }
                   }; 

                saveContactTask.execute((Object[]) null); 
             }

             else
             {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddEditCountry.this);
                alert.setTitle(R.string.errorTitle); 
                alert.setMessage(R.string.errorMessage);
                alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.errorButton, null); 
                alert.show();
             }
          } 
     });
   }

   private void saveContact() 
   {
      DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);

      if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)
      {
          dbConnector.insertContact(nameEt.getText().toString(),
                  capEt.getText().toString(),
                  codeEt.getText().toString(),
                  Donedate.getText().toString(),
                  Notes.getText().toString(),
                  Person.getText().toString(), null




                  );
      }
      else
      {
         dbConnector.updateContact(rowID,
            nameEt.getText().toString(),
            capEt.getText().toString(), 
            codeEt.getText().toString(), 
            Donedate.getText().toString(),
         Notes.getText().toString(),
          Person.getText().toString(), null


         );
      }
   }











   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

       switch(requestCode) {
       case 0:
           if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
               Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
               String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

               Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
               cursor.moveToFirst();

               int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
               String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex); // file path of selected image
               cursor.close();
                       //  Convert file path into bitmap image using below line.
               Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

                       // put  bitmapimage in your imageview
               imageView1.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
           }
       }
    }







}











             mport android.os.AsyncTask;
        import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.app.ListActivity;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.database.Cursor;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuInflater;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
   import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.AdapterView;
   import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
  import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
   import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

   public class CountryList extends ListActivity {

 public static final String ROW_ID = "row_id";
 private ListView conListView;
 private CursorAdapter conAdapter;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    conListView=getListView();
    conListView.setOnItemClickListener(viewConListener);

    // map each name to a TextView
    String[] from = new String[] { "name" };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.countryTextView };
    conAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(CountryList.this, R.layout.country_list,  
        null, from, to);
    setListAdapter(conAdapter); // set adapter
 }


 @Override
 protected void onResume() 
 {
   super.onResume();  
   new GetContacts().execute((Object[]) null);
  } 


 @Override
 protected void onStop() 
 {
   Cursor cursor = conAdapter.getCursor();

   if (cursor != null) 
      cursor.deactivate();

   conAdapter.changeCursor(null);
   super.onStop();
}    


 private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Cursor> 
 {
   DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(CountryList.this);

   @Override
   protected Cursor doInBackground(Object... params)
   {
      dbConnector.open();
      return dbConnector.getAllContacts(); 
   } 

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result)
   {
      conAdapter.changeCursor(result); // set the adapter's Cursor
      dbConnector.close();
   } 
 } 

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
 {
   super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.country_menu, menu);
   return true;
 }   

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
 {
    Intent addContact = new Intent(CountryList.this, AddEditCountry.class);
   startActivity(addContact);
   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }

 OnItemClickListener viewConListener = new OnItemClickListener() 
 {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) 
   {         
      Intent viewCon = new Intent(CountryList.this, ViewCountry.class);
      viewCon.putExtra(ROW_ID, arg3);
      startActivity(viewCon);
   }
 };    

 }








      import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.database.SQLException;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;


     public class DatabaseConnector {

private static final String DB_NAME = "WorldCountries";
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private DatabaseOpenHelper dbOpenHelper;

public DatabaseConnector(Context context) {
    dbOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
}

   public void open() throws SQLException 
   {
      //open database in reading/writing mode
      database = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
   } 

   public void close() 
   {
      if (database != null)
         database.close();
   }       

   public void insertContact(String name, String cap, String code, String  
    LocationEd, String Notes, String Person,byte[] image) 
           {
              ContentValues newCon = new ContentValues();
              newCon.put("name", name);
              newCon.put("cap", cap);
              newCon.put("code", code);

              newCon.put("Location",LocationEd);
              newCon.put("Notes",Notes);
              newCon.put("Person",Person);
              newCon.put("Image", image);

              open();
              database.insert("country", null, newCon);
              close();
           }


           public void updateContact(long id, String name, String  
   cap,String code,String LocationEd, String Notes, String Person ,byte[] image) 
           {
              ContentValues editCon = new ContentValues();
              editCon.put("name", name);
              editCon.put("cap", cap);
              editCon.put("code", code);
              editCon.put("Location", LocationEd);
              editCon.put("Notes", Notes);
              editCon.put("Person", Person);
              editCon.put("Image", image);

              open();
              database.update("country", editCon, "_id=" + id, null);
              close();
           }


           public Cursor getAllContacts() 
           {
              return database.query("country", new String[] {"_id",  
       "name"}, 
                 null, null, null, null, "name");
           }

           public Cursor getOneContact(long id) 
           {
              return database.query("country", null, "_id=" + id, null,  
    null, null, null);
           }

           public void deleteContact(long id) 
           {
              open(); 
              database.delete("country", "_id=" + id, null);
              close();
           }
     }







        import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
     import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

      public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context, String name,
        CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE country (_id integer primary key   
     autoincrement,name text,cap text,code text,Location double,Notes text,Person  
      text,Image Blob);";              
    db.execSQL(createQuery);        
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

   }







       public class ViewCountry extends Activity {

   private long rowID;
   private TextView nameTv;
   private TextView capTv;
   private TextView codeTv; 


   private TextView Locationlb; 
   private TextView Noteslb; 
   private TextView Personlb; 



   private  ImageView imageView2;


   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.view_country);

      setUpViews();
      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
      rowID = extras.getLong(CountryList.ROW_ID); 
   }

   private void setUpViews() {
       nameTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
       capTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.capText);
       codeTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.codeText);

       Locationlb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Location_lbl);



       Noteslb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Notes_lbl);
       Personlb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Person_lbl);


       imageView2= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
          Button Browse2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Browse2);






          Browse2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {               
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                }
            });        























   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume()
   {
      super.onResume();
      new LoadContacts().execute(rowID);
   } 

   private class LoadContacts extends AsyncTask<Long, Object, Cursor> 
   {
      DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(ViewCountry.this);

      @Override
      protected Cursor doInBackground(Long... params)
      {
         dbConnector.open();
         return dbConnector.getOneContact(params[0]);
      } 

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result)
      {
         super.onPostExecute(result);

         result.moveToFirst();
         // get the column index for each data item
         int nameIndex = result.getColumnIndex("name");
         int capIndex = result.getColumnIndex("cap");
         int codeIndex = result.getColumnIndex("code");

         int LocationIndex = result.getColumnIndex("Location");
         int NotesIndex = result.getColumnIndex("Notes");
         int PersonIndex = result.getColumnIndex("Person");





         nameTv.setText(result.getString(nameIndex));
         capTv.setText(result.getString(capIndex));
         codeTv.setText(result.getString(codeIndex));
         Locationlb.setText(result.getString(LocationIndex));


         Noteslb.setText(result.getString(NotesIndex));
         Personlb.setText(result.getString(PersonIndex));




         result.close();
         dbConnector.close();
      }
   } 


   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
   {
      super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.view_country_menu, menu);
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
   {
      switch (item.getItemId())
      {
         case R.id.editItem:
            Intent addEditContact =
               new Intent(this, AddEditCountry.class);

            addEditContact.putExtra(CountryList.ROW_ID, rowID);
            addEditContact.putExtra("name", nameTv.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("cap", capTv.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("code", codeTv.getText());

            addEditContact.putExtra("Location", Locationlb.getText());


            addEditContact.putExtra("Notes", Noteslb.getText());

            addEditContact.putExtra("Person", Personlb.getText());

            startActivity(addEditContact); 
            return true;

         case R.id.deleteItem:
            deleteContact();
            return true;

         default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      } 
   }

   private void deleteContact()
   {

      AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewCountry.this);

      alert.setTitle(R.string.confirmTitle); 
      alert.setMessage(R.string.confirmMessage); 

      alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.delete_btn,
         new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
         {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button)
            {
               final DatabaseConnector dbConnector = 
                  new DatabaseConnector(ViewCountry.this);

               AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object> deleteTask =
                  new AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object>()
                  {
                     @Override
                     protected Object doInBackground(Long... params)
                     {
                        dbConnector.deleteContact(params[0]); 
                        return null;
                     } 

                     @Override
                     protected void onPostExecute(Object result)
                     {
                        finish(); 
                     }
                  };

               deleteTask.execute(new Long[] { rowID });               
            }
         }
      );

      alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_btn, null).show();
    }
        }
```

Comment: try and narrow it down. for example, post the specific error message you get.

Comment: im confuse how to add new field for add image and save in database

Comment: @HayyaAnam : why you want to store images in database because this is not preferable way to store images for Application you just need to more all images in one folder on sdcard and just store image path instead of whole image by converting to String or using BLOB type

Answer (score 0):

I advise to store the URL of the image in database rather than storing the actual Image in BLOB format because all the images stored in database in BLOB format will consume your internal memory.

You can download the images later in lazy loading fashion and you can cache them into your SD card. You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3068012/801437) post for the same.

Good luck :)

Comment: no i wanna add actual image in my database plz help me modify my code is browser image and show on screen but not save in sqllite